# Xamarin Forms DatePicker don't select current date

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a DatePicker in my Xamarin Forms project and when I open DatePicker, calendar comes with current date selected and I click 'done button' but no event triggers. I choose different date it works but I can't trigger the event when I select current date. By the way I wrote my DateSelected method to trigger event but it doesn't work for current date.

Comment: can please send the code what you have done so far ?

Comment: try to handle Done button click event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772096/how-can-we-handle-the-done-button-click-event-for-a-xamarin-forms-picker