# Xamarin.Forms datepicker selects during the selection iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

in my project I used datepicker and in the iOS part while I am choosing a date, datepicker triggers the DateSelected method without tapping 'Done' button. Is there any solution?

Comment: That is the default behavior for iOS. You would need to create a [custom renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40138648/3850012) to capture the **Done** button clicks.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks :)

Comment: @OguzhanO did my answer help you ？if  you solved the issue please mark it as answer ,thanks .

Comment: @ColeXia I used custom renderer for the Done button, this solved my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @hvaughan3 mentioned , this is the default behavior for iOS.

On **DatePicker** control you can capture

- DateSelected : fires everytime when change the date
- Unfocused : fires when click Done button or focus another control.

You can use **Unfocused** to implement your requirement.