# How can i get notification from DatePicker and Timepicker only user presses Done button in Xamarin forms IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i want to know how to get notification from Datepicker and timepicker only when user presses done button in **Xamarin forms IOS**. currently when TimePicker property changed and DatePicker DateSelected is raised when ever picker selected index is changed.

Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Unfocused event?

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

When user press the done button of `DatePicker` and `TimerPicker`, the [unfocused event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.unfocused?view=xamarin-forms) will be fired.

For example:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <app71:myPicker Unfocused="DatePicker_Unfocused"/>

    <TimePicker Unfocused="TimePicker_Unfocused" />

</StackLayout>
```

And in .cs:

```
private void DatePicker_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DatePicker_Unfocused");
}

private void TimePicker_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TimePicker_Unfocused");
}
```

You can also handle the click event in the native Xamarin.iOS project using custom renderer, here is an example of DatePicker:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(myPicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace App71.iOS
{
    public class MyPickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                var toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;
                var doneBtn = toolbar.Items[1];

                doneBtn.Clicked -= DoneBtn_Clicked;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;
                var doneBtn = toolbar.Items[1];

                doneBtn.Clicked += DoneBtn_Clicked;
            }
        }

        void DoneBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoneBtn_Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Refer:

[how-can-we-handle-the-done-button-click-event-for-a-xamarin-forms-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772096/how-can-we-handle-the-done-button-click-event-for-a-xamarin-forms-picker)

[custom-renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers)